# pear quickform2-processing a function

Tags: pear, quickform

i coded this snippet,but the problem is that the **process** function is superseded in quickform2,i want to know how to process any function in the new class of quickform2

```
session_start();
require("db.php");
require_once("HTML/QuickForm2.php");

$form=new HTML_QuickForm2('myform');
$form->addDataSource(new Html_QuickForm2_Datasource_Array(array('subject'=>'mohamed amin')));

$catsql=mysql_query("select id,category from categories order by category");

while($catrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($catsql)){
    $catarr[$catrow['id']]= $catrow['category'];
    }

$select= $form->addElement('select','cat_id',array('size' => 3),array('label' => 'Test Select:','options' => $catarr));


$subject=$form->addElement('text','subject',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>80))->setLabel('عنوان الموضوع');
$body=$form->addElement('textarea','body',array('rows'=>20,'cols'=>80))->setLabel('نص الموضوع');

$submit=$form->addElement('submit',null,array('value'=>'تنفيذ'));

$subject->addFilter('trim');
$subject->addRule('required','من فضلك ادخل عنوان للموضوع');
$body->addRule('required','مطلوب كتابة موضوع');
if($form->validate()){
    $form->toggleFrozen(true);
    $insertid=mysql_insert_id();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $form->process(process_data,false);
    header("Loaction:".$base_dir."viewstory.php?id=".$insertid);
    }
    else {

    echo $form;

        }

function process_data($values){
    $date=date("d/m/y h:i:s");
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into articles(cat_id,user_id,date,subject,body) values (".$values['cat_id'].",".$SESSION_['SESS_userID'].",".$date.",".$values['subject'].",".$values['body'].")");
```

i looked to the doc ,but couldn't find anything related for migration this function
        }

Answer (score 0):

There is no special migration for `process()`, the method was pretty useless. Basically you should just use

```
process_data($form->getValue());
```

now. See this [message in pear-general](http://marc.info/?l=pear-general&m=133105166130784&w=2) for additional info.